# vs code extension for styling css inside html files?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

[image]

My VS Code editor is not styling or autocompleting the CSS I type into my html files.  Should VS Code automatically do this?  And if not, can anyone recommend the correct extension to make this work?

I am using VS Code 1.57.0 and have tried using the "HTML CSS Support" and "IntelliSense for CSS class names" extensions but to no avail.

Comment: did you try to mark it as important? The !important rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a property/value than normal.

Comment: sorry, just to clarify, the css is working as far as rendering goes.  what i am asking here is how to get vs code to detect that i am writing css and color my code appropriately, and also supply autocomplete etc.

Comment: Sorry Andrew i understand now. So it is while you are coding in side your environment.